# (for-each-row scenario).in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

**Query1**

```
cluster(x).database('$systemdb').Operations 
| where Operation == "DatabaseCreate" and Database contains "oci-"| where State =='Completed' 
and  StartedOn between (datetime(2020-04-07) .. 3d)
| distinct Database , StartedOn 
| order by StartedOn desc
```

Output of my query1 is list of databases , now I have to pass each db value into query2 to get buildnumber

**Query2:**

```
set query_take_max_records=5000;
let view=datatable(Property:string,Value:dynamic)[];
let viewFile=datatable(FileName:string)[];
alias database db = cluster(x).database('y');
let latestInfoFile = toscalar((
    union isfuzzy=true viewFile,database('db').['TextFileLogs'] 
    | where FileName contains "AzureStackStampInformation" 
    | distinct FileName 
    | order by FileName 
    | take 1));
union isfuzzy=true view,(
    database('db').['TextFileLogs']
    | where FileName == latestInfoFile
    | distinct LineNumber,FileLineContent
    | order by LineNumber asc
    | summarize StampInfo=(toobject(strcat_array(makelist(FileLineContent,100000), "\r\n")))
    | mvexpand bagexpansion=array StampInfo
    | project Property=tostring(StampInfo[0]), Value=StampInfo[1] 
)|where Property contains "StampVersion" | project BuildNumber = Value;
```

Comment: The question is not clear, can you provide a small concrete example using datatables of the input and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

database() function: is a special scoping function, and it does not support non-constant arguments due to security consideration.
As a result - you cannot use sub-query to fetch list of databases and then operate on this list as input for database() function.

This behavior is described at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/databasefunction?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Syntax

database(stringConstant)

Arguments

stringConstant: Name of the database that is referenced. Database identified can be either DatabaseName or PrettyName. Argument has to be constant prior of query execution, i.e. cannot come from sub-query evaluation.